# How to filter list of tuples?

Tags: nextflow

Hey guys I am kinda new to Nextflow I would like to parse a channel that is a list of tuples that look like that:

```
[ID, [[Type1, file, file], [[Type2, file, file],(...)]
```

I would like to filter it to contain only tuples with Type1 to get:

```
[ID, [[Type1, file, file]]
```

What would be the best approach? I tried .filter() however obviously it returns a full list as soon as it detects Type1 without removing Type2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator and the Groovy [`findAll()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) method with a closure to find the tuples where "Type1" is the first element. For example:

```
workflow {

    ...

    your_channel.map { id, the_list ->
        tuple( id, the_list.findAll { it.first() == "Type1" } )
    }

}
```

Comment: I had to modify it to 
{ it ->
        tuple( it[0], it[1].findAll { it.first() == "Type1" } )
}

And now it works, thank you ^^

Comment: No worries at all @AggresiveHayBale. I just assumed your channel emits collections comprising of two elements (the ID and a list of tuples). Best to avoid using the same parameter name twice though.